# Cakephp ORM is pulling every column

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the snippet of code, I want the the following query to pull all products associated with category, a belongs to many relationship.

That works, but even though I have declare a select, it still retrieves every column in product, i just want the four columns which I declare.

I look over and read the documentation at http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

```
$Product= $categoryObj->find()->contain([
            'Product' => function ($q) {
                return $q
                    ->select(['name', 'url', 'published', 'site_id'])
                    ->where(['published' => 1, 'site_id' => 2]);
                }
            ])
            ->where(['id'=> $id])
            ->toArray();
```

Comment: I have a query exactly like yours and it works for me on my 1:N model relationship, remember that you have to call the foreign key on your select, otherwise you won't get any results related to your category. I guess it is category_id or something like that.

Comment: I'm getting results, the problem is it's selecting every column not just the columns declared in select()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `autoFields(false)` after the `select()`. The code would be as follows:

```
$Product= $categoryObj->find()
    ->contain([
        'Product' => function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['name', 'url', 'published', 'site_id'])
                ->autoFields(false)
                ->where(['published' => 1, 'site_id' => 2]);
        }
    ])
    ->where(['id'=> $id])
    ->toArray();
```